# Dependency Property reverting to default value after navigation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm missing something really obvious here but just cant work it out :(

I have a 2 page windows store application with a `Dependency Property` called Seconds.
If you click the start button a timer will start and the value of `Seconds` will decrease as expected
BUT if I navigate to `Page2` and back again to `MainPage` the DP is reset to Default Value in UI despite the actual value being correct.

I can see this by putting a breakpoint on the _timer.tick event the `Seconds` DP isnt at its default value but decreasing as expected as the timer is still running. I would like this reflected in the UI
Any help appreciated?

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnNav" Content="Page 2" Width="150" Height="60" Click="btnNav_Click"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start" Width="150" Height="60" Click="btnStart_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">            
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtSeconds" FontSize="25" Text="{Binding Path=Seconds}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.cs

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
 {
    private static DispatcherTimer _timer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (s, args) =>
            {


                if (_timer == null)
                {
                    _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
                    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
                    _timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
                        {                                
                            Seconds--;
                        };
                }

                this.DataContext = this;
            };
    }


    public int Seconds
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SecondsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SecondsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Seconds.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Seconds", typeof(int), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(100));


    private void btnNav_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Page2.xaml

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Click="AppBarButton_Click"></AppBarButton>
</Grid>
```

Page2.cs

```
public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem is not in DP. When you navigate back to same page, page is recreated. You can verify that by putting breakpoint on MainPage constructor. Since after navigating back to main page, you haven't started timer again so no update in GUI.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Sorry forgot to add _timer is static so is still running on return to page and tick event being hit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comment :

> Problem is not in DP. When you navigate back to same page, page is
>   recreated. You can verify that by putting breakpoint on MainPage
>   constructor. Since after navigating back to main page, you haven't
>   started timer again so no update in GUI.

For your statement

> _timer is static.

that change nothing at all. Since timer is static and won't be null in case of second load so `Tick` event never gets hooked up for second instance of MainPage.

`Tick` event is getting hit for first instance of MainPage. **First instance never gets destroyed because of memory leak you have induced by making timer as static. So, it is still decrementing Seconds value for first instance and not current instance.**

Move `Tick` event hooking outside of null check and you will see GUI will update but starting from 100 onwards because new instance will have default value 100.

```
 if (_timer == null)
 {
     _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
     _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
 }
 _timer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
            {                                
               Seconds--;
            };
```

Comment: Thx Rohit thats it. I had a mental block on the 2 instances for some reason doh! live and learn

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you navigate forward to new instance of MainPage, so it has own (default) value of DP.

I guess you're looking for [GoBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.goback.aspx) method of Frame

Comment: Updated question _timer is static and still running and Seconds DP is counting down correctly but not being reflected in UI on returning to MainPage

Comment: @dellywheel not reflected means not changing at all?
did you tried to navigate back using `code` private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }
`code`

Comment: Sorry, using `private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.GoBack();
    }
`

Comment: thx for comment. yes not changing in UI despite DP changing. GoBack() = same